# Setting up roles in ASP.NET webform

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

apologies if this question seems basic, but I am quite stuck despite alot of googling
I am trying to setup an ASP.NET webform project to use roles, I am creating users using the following:

```
 protected void CreateUser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var manager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        var signInManager = Context.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationSignInManager>();
        var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = Email.Text, Email = Email.Text, FirstName = FirstName.Text, LastName = LastName.Text };
        IdentityResult result = manager.Create(user, Password.Text);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
           
            string code = manager.GenerateEmailConfirmationToken(user.Id);
            string callbackUrl = IdentityHelper.GetUserConfirmationRedirectUrl(code, user.Id, Request);
            manager.SendEmail(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>.");
           
            signInManager.SignIn( user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);
           
            IdentityHelper.RedirectToReturnUrl(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"], Response);
        }
        else 
        {
            ErrorMessage.Text = result.Errors.FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
```

I am struggling to setup the project to use roles and add them to the users, could anyone please direct me in the right direction? A lot of the information available online relates to MVC or .NET Core projects and I cannot seem to implement them to my webform project mainly due to my limited knowledge of .net (new to this).
Much appreciate your help

Comment: Do you see/have the database setup, and have you added roles to that database? it not clear how much of a long drawn out tutorial you asking for here? And I assume  you using "owin", or perhaps are you using legacy FBA (forms based authentication)?

Comment: Are you forced to use webforms for this? because I really wouldn't, if you don't have to. It's very much a legacy thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, since database roles tend to be a "one time" setup, then I usually just directly open the table in edit mode, and add the few roles I want to use.

If you using SQL server, then just fire up SQL studio, and right click on the table, (choose edit 200 rows option). I then just type in the roles, and that is quite much the end of this.

And, if you using a "attached" database in which asp.net attaches the database (and I tend to only recommend this for development), then view/display the database exploer, and the "view" data option ALSO allows you to edit.

Hence, you see this:

[image]

So, we just opened the roles table directly, and then I just enter the few roles I need/want.

So, say now this:

[image]

As for the "id", I just again manually type in 1, then 2 and so on. I can't recall ever having more then about 5-8 roles anyway, so it not a big deal, and in 99% of cases not worth the time to write code to add roles to the database.

However, you can add roles this way:

vb:

```
    Dim strRole = "ZooRole"
    Using context = New ApplicationDbContext()
        Dim MyRoleStore = New RoleStore(Of IdentityRole)(context)
        MyRoleStore.CreateAsync(New IdentityRole(strRole))
    End Using
```

c#

```
var strRole = "ZooRole";
using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext())
{
    var MyRoleStore = new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context);
    MyRoleStore.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(strRole));
}
```

So, its rather easy to add some roles. Once of course you have the roles you want "defined" and added to the database, then you can/should be able to use the built in methods to add a new user to a role.

It is not clear if you issue/challenge here is adding/creating some new roles, of which THEN you can create users, and then add users to some defined roles.

So, trouble adding users? Trouble adding Roles? Trouble adding users to a given role? Which task?

In fact, during testing, I often have opened the above tables mannually, and simple edited the data by hand. (often, this becomes a chicken and egg issue. If I have a page setup to add/select users and assign roles, I can't get to that secuired page! (might have a role called "SiteAdmin". So, I often will just edit manaully my roles table (add a SiteAdmin), and add myselft to the "SiteAdmin" role.

it is actually quite easy to add some roles to a existing user manually as per above (ie: open the role table and add a few roles, and then open the AspNetUserRoles table and add myself to the SiteAdmin role (or whatever role you cooked up and floats your boat).